# VSO Build agent failing with missing pfx

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce, tfsbuild, azure-devops

I'm using the [VSO build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/overview) to compile a clickonce project. We have a certificate for signing the manifest, however msbuild keeps failing due to the certificate not being in the user's certificate store. The certificate is password protected. I think the vso build agent runs under my credentials on the server (since I installed it), but I am not sure. I installed the certificate under my credentials and it still fails. I even tried to install the certificate in the local machine store and it still failed.
[image]

How can I get this build to pass if the certificate is the only issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation I found that the vsoAgent service was installed under the user credentials *devtools*. Then I recalled setting up that user specifically for the build agent. I logged in as that user and installed the .pfx certificate needed for clickonce using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695339/how-do-you-install-a-certificate-in-a-pfx-file-in-to-the-personal-container-of-t). The original error was replaced with something more generic "Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store" and after a clean build I got "SignTool.exe not found". I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32414169/1215018) and now my issue is resolved.